# How to align Paging toolbar in middle of grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I want to align pagging tool bar in middle of grid. Is there any config parameter or css by which i can achieve that?

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
id:'simpsonsStore',
autoLoad: false,
fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
pageSize: 2
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'pagingstore.js',  
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'items',
        totalProperty: 'total'
    }
}});
store.load({
params:{
    start:0,
    limit: itemsPerPage
}});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
title: 'Simpsons',
store: store,
columns: [
    { header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
    { header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
    { header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
],
width: 400,
height: 125,
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
    store: store,   
    dock: 'bottom',
    displayInfo: true
}],
renderTo: Ext.getBody()});
```

Comment: pagingtoolbar assigns a default layout `(layout: 'hbox')`, try setting hbox layout `pack:'center'`

Comment: @MMT Clever, but it doesn't work with `displayInfo: true` because of the existing filler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure your paging toolbar this way would do the trick:

```
{
    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
    store: store,
    dock: 'bottom',
    displayInfo: true,

    items: ['->'],
    prependButtons: true
}
```

This relies on having another toolbar filler `'->'` on the right of the paging items, so if you set [`displayInfo`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging-cfg-displayInfo) to `false`, you should use MMT's solution instead. <s>this instead:</s>

```
{
    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
    store: store,
    dock: 'bottom',

    displayInfo: false,
    listeners: {
        single: true,
        render: function() {
            var items = this.items;
            items.insert(0, Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Fill'));
            items.add(Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Fill'));
        }
    }
}
```